# How to display open file descriptors with thread id without using lsof command

Tags: linux, file-descriptors

How to display open file descriptors with thread id without using `lsof`?
I know a similar question exists but the answer doesn't include thread details.

Answer (score 4):

On top of the answers given, it is perhaps worth mentioning that in Linux, all threads started by a process, typically share the same set of file descriptors. Thus, both:

`ls /proc/$parent_pid/task/$task/fd` 
and 
`ls /proc/$parent_process/fd`

would typically produce the same output, which implies that child processes inherit the file descriptors referenced by their parent.
The 'lsof' manual actually specifies that too under the -K option documentation:

> "In  general threads and  tasks inherit the files of the caller,      but
>   may   close some and open others, so lsof always reports all      the open
>   files of threads and tasks."

So to eliminate any potential ambiguity (perhaps created by the previous answers), listing `/proc/$parent_pid/$task/fd` does not guerantee that $task was the thread that refrences the file descriptor ids in that directory. If you need a reliable way of telling which thread opened a particular file descriptor, you can `strace` the program to track system calls like `open()`, that require the kernel to assign a file descriptor.

Comment: The assumption in this answer as well in the cited lsof man page seems to be in contradiction with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1522077 which includes code-of-proof: "Threads share the same memory, so they share the same variables. If you close socket in parent thread, it will be also closed in child thread." According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364660/are-threads-implemented-as-processes-on-linux, Linux pthreads use Linux tasks via the clone() syscall with appropriate flags.

Comment: I second that. I tried opening two threads from the main thread, t1 and t2. In the main thread I opened a file f1, in t2 a file f2 (different files). Browsing /proc/PID/task/*/fd shows both files open in all three threads (main, t1 and t2).

Answer (score 2):

On Linux:

```
ls -l /proc/*/task/*/fd
```

Contrary to `lsof`, it only lists file descriptors, not mmapped files, root and current directories.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can inspect `/proc/TID/fd....` I don't understand what's the issue here.