# Why do threads have their own PID?

Tags: linux, process, multithreading

I'm using htop and looking at a process (rg) which launched multiple threads to search for text in files, here's the tree view in `htop`:

```
PID   Command
1019  |- rg 'search this'
1021     |- rg 'search this'
1022     |- rg 'search this'
1023     |- rg 'search this'
```

Why am I seeing PIDs for the process' threads? I thought threads didn't have a PID and they just shared their parent's PID.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Linux, each thread has a pid, and that’s what `htop` shows. The “process” to which all the threads belong is the thread whose pid matches its thread group id.

In your case, `grep Tgid /proc/1021/status` would show the value 1019 (and this would be true for all the `rg` identifiers shown by `htop`).

See [Are threads implemented as processes on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364660/86440) for details.