# What starts threads in Linux OS?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, process, scheduling, thread

I am currently investigate a question related to threads in the Linux OS. I know that processes are started by the scheduler in Linux Kernel, but what starts threads inside a process - Linux Kernel scheduler or another service in Linux Kernel?

Please help with this question.

Thanks

Comment: Start ? What do you mean by that ? (From the order given by a program to cpu's PC being initialized with the thread's start text address ?)

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, processes and threads are created by calling [`fork`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [`clone`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), and other similar system calls and C library functions. Most programmers won’t call `clone` directly; instead they’d use a thread library (pthreads, C++ threads, and whatever other representation is used in their language of choice).

Both processes and threads are *started* by the scheduler. In fact, the scheduler in Linux mostly concerns itself with threads, and a process with “no” threads is really a thread with no siblings in the same process. See [Why do threads have their own PID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/670836/86440)